# datepicker being transparent in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, internet-explorer

I have used a datepicker function in my jsp.

```
$(function() {
$( "#id" ).datepicker({maxDate: '0'});
});
```

working fine in Firefox but in case of Internet Explorer the background is being transparent. 
Is there any way to overcome it without updating the browser?

Comment: Have you added relevant CSS compatible with the jquery version?

Comment: What about your `.ui-datepicker table`.. See [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ie8-transparency-problem-with-datepikcer)

Comment: where to put it? @tailorBird

Comment: In your `datepicker` CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this for example:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hJC46/)

```
.ui-datepicker table {width: 100%; font-size: .9em; border-collapse: collapse; margin:0 0 .4em; background-color: #000000; }
```

You can change the `background-color` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be on how you reference your CSS and JQuery library.
Please share your reference.